# Aiogram InputFile

Tags: python, input, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

Code:

```
From handlers import TOKEN
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InputFile

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

music = InputFile(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\файлы для примера\Apple-tv-iso-b-01-top.jpg')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['Start'])
async def process_hello(message: types.File):
await bot.send_file(message.from_user.id, music)

if __name__ == '__main__':
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=TypeError("send_file() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'file' and 'payload'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
(sistem errors)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\python\боты телеграмм\3\menu.py", line 12, in process_hello
    await bot.send_file(message.from_user.id, music)
TypeError: send_file() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'file' and 'payload'
```